# iReport Changing Array sizes

Tags: arrays, jasper-reports

I currently have a report containing 3 variables splitting and trimming a string to be wrote into different columns based on a delimiter of '/'.
E.g.

```
$F{Batch}.split("/" ,3)[1].trim()
```

I have come across and issue where the first section of the batch number may not appear causing my report to error as there is no 3rd "section"

I believe the only solution is to add a conditional statement in each expression to check the array size and only write in the 2nd two columns.

In pseudo english:
Column 1

```
    IF Arraysize = 3 THEN
   $F{Batch}.split("/" ,3)[0].trim() 
   ELSE 'do not write to this column'
```

Column 2

```
 IF Arraysize = 3 THEN
   $F{Batch}.split("/" ,3)[1].trim() 
   ELSE $F{Batch}.split("/" ,3)[0].trim()
```

Column 3

```
  IF Arraysize = 3 THEN
       $F{Batch}.split("/" ,3)[2].trim() 
       ELSE $F{Batch}.split("/" ,3)[1].trim()
```

To summarise I am looking for the method to write the values into the final two columns in array if the array size ends up being 2 instead of 3.

Thank you

Comment: What expression are you using now? And what problem do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself:

Instead of looking at the last section of the array I using a substring length to pull the final characters. But any errors in the array if "section 2" doesn't exist.

only issue is it will have duplicate data if there is a missing section but in my particular case it is acceptable.

```
$F{Batch}.substring($F{Batch}.length()-10)
```